# Most concise fix for .weekday returning wrong day

Tags: ios, swift, date

I'm trying to get the current day of the week, this code is returning one day in the future. What is the most concise fix for this?

```
currentDay = DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols[Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())]


print(currentDay)
```

Comment: That's bad habit. You are doing too much in one single line. And when it's not working, it's a nightmare. You should separate. `let weekdaysSymbols = DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols; let weekday = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date()), let currentDay = weekDaysSymbols[weekday]` See each values. Which one seems weird to you? Debugging is important.

Comment: Yeah, I see your point, it's more clear and easier to debug when the code is more separated. Noted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In iOS, the weekdaySymbols starts from Sunday to Saturday. It's an array so indexes range from 0 to 6

All you need to do is subtract the weekDay number by 1 to get the right day like below:

```
let weekDay = Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: Date())

let currentDay = DateFormatter().weekdaySymbols[weekDay-1]
```

Also, note that when you try to fetch the weekDay number for Sunday from Calendar API it will return you `1`

Please find the developer documentation snapshot for a reference

[image]

Comment: Okay, got it. The mismatch between .weekday and .weekdaySymbols is kind of weird but it's a pretty simple fix. Thanks.